# stack overflow when executing recursive lisp function

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, stack-overflow, clisp

I get a '-Program stack overflow' prompt in clisp when I try to execute the following recursive function that, I believe, returns the most common element in a list:

```
(defun greater-member (lst)
  (cond  ((null (cdr lst))
                (cons (car lst) (count-if #'(lambda (x) (eql x (car lst))) lst)))
         ((>= (count-if #'(lambda (x) (eql x (car lst))) lst)
              (count-if #'(lambda (x) (eql x (car (remove (car lst) lst)))) lst))
                (greater-member (remove (car (remove (car lst) lst)) lst)))
         (t (greater-member (remove (car lst) lst)))))
```

e.g **greater-number** should return as follows:

```
>(greater-number '(a a a b b b b c))
(b . 4)
```

May I ask, what is causing the overflow? I've gotten rid of all the little syntax errors 
by repeatedly executing **greater-number** in clisp- the function seems to hold logically.

Comment: Why not debug the function using TRACE, STEP or printing the argument?

Comment: I haven't heard of those functions before actually. I'll have a look at them.

Comment: This book explains the basics: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Comment: Thanks- I've realized the bug now, using TRACE. Thank you for the link also.

Comment: (count-if #'(lambda (x) (eql x (car lst))) lst) is (count (car lst) lst)

Comment: Thanks for that- I wasn't aware of the existence of count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've realized my error now.

Looking at my **null** test, rather than

```
(null (cdr lst))
```

I should have

```
(null (remove (car lst) lst))
```

So that the redundant, lesser occurring unique elements are removed.

Comment: can you explain how you used `trace` here (it would complete the answer in a way that will help other users)?  Also, since this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437)!

Comment: I have removed the 'trace' output since I cannot reconcile the meaning of the output with the code.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more optimized version:

```
(defun most-common (list)
  (let* ((len 0) (hash (make-hash-table))
         (max-occurences 0)
         key
         (max-possible
          (dolist (i list (ceiling len 2))
            (incf (gethash i hash 0))
            (incf len))))
    (maphash #'(lambda (a b)
                 (if (>= b max-possible)
                     (return-from most-common
                       (if (> b max-occurences) a key))
                     (progn
                       (when (> b max-occurences)
                         (setf key a max-occurences b))
                       (decf max-possible (max 1 (floor b 2))))))
             hash) key))
```

Comment: you might be able to use this: `(incf (gethash i hash 0))`

Comment: Thanks, this function contains many new concepts- I'll shorty cover hash tables, so this will be a good example.